# jquery ajax loop only returning last value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call to several different services. I know my array `var log` is being overwritten by each successive call, but I can't figure out how to change the logic to append the next array instead of overwriting.

```
$.ajax($.extend({}, ajaxDefaults, source, {
                data: data,
                success: function(events) {
                    events = events || [];
                    var res = applyAll(success, this, arguments);
                    if ($.isArray(res)) {
                        events = res;
                    }
                    callback(events);


                  var log = log || [];
                      for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
                        log.push(events[i]);
                    }
                    console.log(log);

                },
                error: function() {
                    applyAll(error, this, arguments);
                    callback();
                },
                complete: function(events) {
                    applyAll(complete, this, arguments);
                    popLoading();

                }
            }));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a problem of scope. You're redeclaring 'var log' inside of the $.ajax success() function (and thus overwriting it). Declare var log outside of $.ajax and just push the new results into that array.

Try the following:

```
var log = [];
$.ajax($.extend({}, ajaxDefaults, source, {
    data: data,
    success: function(events) {
        events = events || [];
        var res = applyAll(success, this, arguments);
        if ($.isArray(res)) {
            events = res;
        }
        callback(events);

        for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
            log.push(events[i]);
        }
        console.log(log);

    },
    error: function() {
        applyAll(error, this, arguments);
        callback();
    },
    complete: function(events) {
        applyAll(complete, this, arguments);
        popLoading();

    }
}));
```

Comment: yes the var log = log || []; creates a new object each time

Comment: thank you! That makes sense. I thought var log = log || []; would create a new log if log was undefined.

Comment: Using a global variable would work: log = log || []; It's just when you redeclare the variable with 'var log' that you're overwriting it.